# Calling a class method in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Game model and a GamesController. These represent a collection of sporting events. I then have a Phrase model that is simply a collection of random phrases. Phrases don't belong to any games and games don't have any phrases. However, I do want to display a random phrase inside Games#index.

I thought I would use a class method on the Game model to pull in the phrases:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.pull_phrase
    Phrase.all.shuffle.limit(1)
  end
end
```

Then in `GamesController` I have:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @games = Game.all
    @next_games = Game.where(["date > ?", Time.now]).all
    @schedule = @next_games[0..4]
  end

  def phrases
    @phrase = Game.pull_phrase
  end   
end
```

Then in my view I just want to output `@phrase`

I'm not getting any errors, but it doesn't look like I'm pulling in anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to set the variable `@phrase` inside the index action. Call `@phrase=Game.pull_phrase` inside the `GamesController#index`.

```rb
def index
    @games = Game.all
    @next_games = Game.where(["date > ?", Time.now]).all
    @schedule = @next_games[0..4]
    @phrase = Game.pull_phrase
    ##Alternative
    @phrase = Phrase.all.sample
end
```

```rb
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.pull_phrase
    Phrase.all.sample
  end
end
```

**Note** that you don't even need to declare the `Game#pull_phrase` class function, since this case is quite trivial(see Alternative)

Comment: That gives me an ActiveRecord::Relation error. Do I need to establish a relationship even though no id's on either model are associated with the other?

Comment: yes! I believe you can't call `limit()` on an Array, see edit.

Comment: Perfect. I wasn't aware of the sample() method. Thanks very much!

Comment: Truly handy method. You can also pass a numeric param to it `sample(n)` to get n samples. Actually, you don't even need to `shuffle` before, since it selects *n* samples **randomly**.  ;)